# Accessing resources on classpath using parent folder sign (../)

Tags: java, resources, jar, classpath

I am trying to access resource on classpath using `getResourceAsStream()`:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
```

If path is something like this: `/net/original/xsdtestxml.xml`, then I have no problems.
However, I have situations where I must use "go to parent" sign `../` to access certain files. I am constructing path manually based on certain parameters.

Final result is something like this:

```
/net/original/../original/xsdtestxml.xml
```

This works fine in Eclipse. It works fine when I run it outside of Eclipse (from command line in programs target folder where .class are contained). However, as soon as I pack those in jar file, it throws `NullPointerException`.

Is there a possibility for `getResourceAsStream()` to support such a format after exported to jar? If not, is there a Java/ Utility class that can get file path without `../` signs? For example to convert `/net/original/../original/xsdtestxml.xml` to `/net/original/xsdtestxml.xml` format?

**One possible solution:**

There is a `URI` class found in `java.net` package that does what I need. You simply create `URI` object with constructor or use static `create(String)` method. Then you call `normalize()` method and can get string path using `toString()` or `getPath()` methods.

Here is the example of code that worked for me:

```
String finalPath = URI.create(inputPath).normalize().getPath();
```

`inputPath` is path that can contain `../` literals.
This perfectly converts `/net/original/../original/xsdtestxml.xml` to `/net/original/xsdtestxml.xml` which is just what I needed to access file from jar on classpath.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access files inside a jar, I recommend opening and reading the jar file with [JarFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html) and [JarFile.entries()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html#entries%28%29).

For example:

```
String s = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getFile();
JarFile jf = new JarFile(java.net.URLDecoder.decode(s, "UTF-8"));
// ...
```

Note that `URLDecoder.decode()` decodes something such as `%20` (— to a whitespace) after calling `getFile()`…

Comment: I need to access files that are stored in jar that is already on classpath. Your solution shows how to access files on any other jarfile (not necessarily on classpath), like a zip. This might come handy later, but I need way to access file in jar on classpath that are using parent directory literal ../ like /net/original/../original/xsdtestxml.xml.

Comment: I've just tried with simple `java.io.File`: I have a file at `/media/data/a.png`, and a folder `/media/data/tmp`. Then this file `new File("/media/data/tmp/../a.png")` pointed to correct `a.png`. Because all other methods such as `length()`, `isFile()`… returned correct values. Would it help you?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. `java.io.File` access files on computer's file system. In my case: I have file that is inside jar file and that jar file is on application's classpath (added using `-cp` argument when running `java`). I tried approach with removing `../` literals from path and I found one solution. I don't have enough reputation so I edited my initial question. That worked fine for me.

Comment: I think the path got from classpath is pointed to real file on the system. If you have a current working folder, or the root folder where parent symbol (`..`) works, you can combine that path with the path you obtain from classpath. Sorry I'm not sure if it's right or wrong… Oh congrats, I've just seen your solution  :-)